# Send data to activity with sharedpreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Is possible to send data to another activity without starting the activity? And if so is it possible to achieve this with sharedpreferences

Comment: When do want to make use of that data in another activity? When it is launched, right? So, what you can do is save data to SharedPreferences and extract it from there at time of launching the activity.

Comment: I appreciate the response. But could provide an example of how to extract the data from sharedprefrences

Comment: Already given the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save data in sender `Activity`:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(<Name>, <Mode>);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putInt(<KEY>, <VALUE>).commit();
// Save other stuffs here
```

Extract data in receiver `Activity`:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(<Name>, <Mode>);
int value = prefs.getInt(<KEY>, <DEFAULT_VALUE>);
```

Comment: Cool.:) Accept this as answer so that it is helpful for other future users too